# command pattern vs Simple factory pattern in C#

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

I understood command pattern belongs to behavioral pattern and simple factory pattern mainly solves the object Creation issues. But when comes in to implementation I feel both follows similar steps.

```
public interface ICommand
{
    string Name { get; }
    void Execute();
} 
public class StartCommand : ICommand
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am executing StartCommand");
    } 
    public string Name
    {
        get { return "Start"; }
    }
} 
public class StopCommand : ICommand
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am executing StopCommand");
    } 
    public string Name
    {
        get { return "Stop"; }
    }
}
public class Invoker
{
    ICommand cmd = null;
    public ICommand GetCommand(string action)
    {
        switch (action)
        {
            case "Start":
                cmd = new StartCommand();
                break;
            case "Stop":
                cmd = new StopCommand();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return cmd;
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Invoker invoker = new Invoker();
        // Execute Start Command
        ICommand command = invoker.GetCommand("Start");
        command.Execute();
        // Execute Stop Commad
        command = invoker.GetCommand("Stop");
        command.Execute();
        Console.WriteLine("Command Pattern demo");
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

and this is an example for simple factory pattern.

```
 interface IGet
    {
        string ConC(string s1, string s2);
    }

    class clsFirst : IGet
    {
        public string ConC(string s1, string s2)
        {
            string Final = "From First: " + s1 + " and " + s2;
            return Final;
        }
    }

    class clsSecond : IGet
    {
        public string ConC(string s1, string s2)
        {
            string Final = "From Second: " + s1 + " and " + s2;
            return Final;
        }
    } 
    class clsFactory
    {
        static public IGet CreateandReturnObj(int cChoice)
        {
            IGet ObjSelector = null;

            switch (cChoice)
            {
                case 1:
                    ObjSelector = new clsFirst();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    ObjSelector = new clsSecond();
                    break;
                default:
                    ObjSelector = new clsFirst();
                    break;
            }
            return ObjSelector;

        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IGet ObjIntrface = null;
            int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            ObjIntrface = clsFactory.CreateandReturnObj(input);
            string res = ObjIntrface.ConC("First", "Second");

        }
    }
```

I couldnt see any difference in the implementation. Can someone help me to understand this?

Comment: The fact you've used factory pattern to create commands for commands pattern does not make one similar to another...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Invoker` is the factory pattern, but not commands:

```
public interface ICommandFactory
{
    ICommand CreateCommand(string action);
}

public class Invoker : ICommandFactory
{
    public ICommand CreateCommand(string action)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

> Command Pattern is a behavioral design pattern in which an object is used to encapsulate all information needed to perform an action or trigger an event at a later time

So your `StartCommand` and `StopCommand` classes only implement the Command Pattern.

---

**UPDATE**

In the second example, where you implemented a simple factory, the `clsFirst` and `clsSecond` are not commands, because their naming does not imply a capture of any input or a context to perform an action on - they are just classes that implement same interface. You have to have a logical `Invoke` or `Execute` method that implies an action on something (and sometimes you can undo that action). But if you are not a human being, but some sort of an AI, the `IGet` and `string ConC(string s1, string s2)` can totally be the definition of a command and an action for you :)

Once again, there is nothing in common between factory and a command. You can use factory to create commands, but it's optional. And you can use factory to create anything, besides commands.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I would like to know this in detail. I have updated with a sample of simple factory pattern also. Could you please share your thoughts on how i can differentiate both?